# "Proper" project setup in intellij (coming from eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I am moving from eclipse to intellij, or at least trying it out. I've read that the idiomatic/proper way to separate out module groups into different intellij projects, however I am missing out on being able to search for usages.

I have a database DAO layer (maven) module, which is used by several other java modules. In my eclipse install, I have a huge module list, separated out/filtered by working sets, and thus when I click on "Find Usages" in eclipse because all modules are loaded it will find the classes in other modules that call the methods I'm searching on.

If I am using intellij correctly (which I'm not sure I am), maven module groups warrant their own projects in the same way you might use a working set in eclipse. This is great so far for what little I've used it for, however when considering an API change to the module, the "Find Usages" in Initellij can't find calling methods in modules that aren't in the project (which is obvious, of course, but not helpful).

So I'm basically figuring that this is actually a relatively normal issue and there is a "proper" way to do this. Am I wrong in my assertion that the module groups should be broken up in the way I have? Is there a way to tell Intellij that these *other* projects refer to the one I'm changing? Some alternative?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Are you opening the "master" pom instead of the modules ones in Intellij?

Comment: It isn't one massive multi-module project. The DAO module isn't actually a sub-module of anything, but is pulled in like an external dependency would be.